# Swipe Gestures on GridView not working anymore

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview

a while ago ive added Swipe Gestures (from Left To Right and from Right to Left) to my GridView. The GridView is a calendar, that should switch to the next or to to the previous month when youre swiping. To achieve this i used this class:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
            float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();

            if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            // Left swipe
            if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onSwipeLeft();

                // Right swipe
            } else if (-diff < SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                onSwipeRight();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("OnSwipeTouchListener", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"></ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"></Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendarheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:verticalSpacing="-5dp"
    android:visibility="visible"></GridView>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
            android:numColumns="7"
            android:verticalSpacing="-5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"></GridView>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/keyYellow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calendar"
            android:background="@drawable/gelb_ellipse" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/keyGrey"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyYellow"
            android:background="@drawable/grau_ellipse" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/keyGreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyGrey"
            android:background="@drawable/gruen_ellipse" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyYellowExplanation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calendar"
            android:background="@drawable/gruen_ellipse" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/test"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/test"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test"
            android:text="Restmüll &amp; Altpapier"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyGreenExplanation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyYellowExplanation"
            android:background="@drawable/gruen_ellipse" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/test2"
            android:text="Restmüll &amp; Altpapier"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyYellowExplanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/keyYellow"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/keyYellow"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyYellow"
            android:text="Gelber Sack &amp; Biomüll"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyGreenExplanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/keyGreen"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/keyGrey"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyGrey"
            android:text="Restmüll &amp; Altpapier"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/keyGreyExplanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/keyGreen"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/keyGreen"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyGreen"
            android:text="Aktueller Tag"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/my_hide_animation"
            fab:menu_fab_label="your_label_here"
            fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/my_show_animation"
            fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
            fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
            fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
            fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
            fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
            fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
            fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
            fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
            fab:menu_labels_position="left"
            fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
            fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
            fab:menu_labels_style="@style/YourCustomLabelsStyle"
            fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
            fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
            fab:menu_openDirection="up"
            fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
            fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
            fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
            fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
            fab:menu_showShadow="true">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/alarmForAllDates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_invitation_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Erinnerungen komplett"
                app:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/alarmForCurrentMonth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_invitation_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Erinnerungen akt. Monat"
                app:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/deleteAllAlarms"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_do_not_disturb_on_white_24dp"
                app:fab_label="Erinnerungen löschen"
                app:fab_size="mini" />

        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This way doesent work anymore, because the e1 variable in the onFling method is always null. Ive read a few stackoverflow posts that deal with the same question but i didnt find a solution. Is there any solution to implement the swipe gesture in my GridView?

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you found solution?